# Carousal - display item height dynamic

Tags: javascript, css, html, carousel

I am using [GlideJS](http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/) to display a carousal. The problem is that each item automatically takes the height of the item with the most content. This results into white space between items with less content and HTML elements that follow after the carousal. 
To illustrate this problem I have created the following Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/thx03jc7/38/

```
<div class="module module--horizontal">
  <div id="Carousel" class="glide">
   please see the above Fiddle for full code example
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the height of each item dynamic and thus remove the white space between the items and HTML elements that follow after the carousal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use autoheight property:

```
var carousel = $('#Carousel').glide({
    type: 'carousel',
    startAt: 1,
    touchDistance: 2,
    autoplay: 0,
    autoheight: true
});
```

All options: http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/docs.html#options

Comment: Thanks, that works, I will set this as the right answer, I feel stupid for not seeing that earlier. However it seems that 'autoheight: true' makes the carousal dissappear when it is in a collapsed div (see: https://jsfiddle.net/7dma7L84/21/ ). Do you happen to have any idea on how to diplay the carousal with autoheight in a collapsed div?

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap your text inside another `div` in your `.box` (like for your first item in the fiddle) you can add the following css

```
.box > div{
   height: 200px; //or whatever height you wish
 }
```

[here's the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thx03jc7/40/)